# Multiple socket connection TCP C#

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I'm new to socket programming and I'm trying to do a simple login with sockets.
The server has a list of users and password, and the client connects by sending a request with username and password.
In case he logs in successfully I want to save a new session, so he can use more commands...
How can I save a session per a client?
Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Making an array of values? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

It depends if your connection will stay open for the entire session, or if the clients will open/close connections throughout (like how a web server works).

In the first case, you can simply save state data along with a reference to the socket object for the connection.

In the second case, you'll need to give each client a unique identifier (a session ID), which can be a key into a dictionary on the server side containing state data.

If this is just an experiment to learn sockets, then this should get you going. Keep in mind that if you are doing this "for real" (on the Internet), then security concerns go far deeper than just session IDs.

Comment: This is an experiment in order to learn sockets..
I'm trying the second option, but I don't know how to make a unique identifier for each client, I tried making a "Session" counter, and then when the users logs in, a session object is created with the session counter, and then I want to check for example - If the session is active, then allow him to do more... In order to do that, I need somehow to check his session ID in runtime...

Comment: I figured as much :) Have fun!

Comment: How can I save a unique identifier that will not reset everytime a new client connects? I tried to save the user name and his session ID into a object "Session", the problem is if I open two clients at the same time, and one connects, then the second one could do the same things as he was connected too (eventhough he isn't)

Comment: You need to have multiple `Session` objects stored in a `Dictionary<Session>`, indexed by session ID.